# GTK Clickable Text inside Text View/Buffer

Tags: url, events, onclick, editor, gtk4

How to make a portion of text inside a GTKTextView to be clickable, so that clicking on the specified portion will trigger some event? And, moreover, how to obtain the exact portion of the text being clicked in the event that is triggered?

Comment: I am using gtk4, and `g_signal_connect(widget, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(callback), ptr)` (which, according to materials I've read on docs and forums would have worked in GTK3, but this is GTK4) causes compiler errors, the compiler fails to recognize `GdkEventButton` also. How exactly in gtk4 should one inject clickability into a text view?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see that GtkGestures should be used to manage this sort of stuff now in GTK4. Sorry for wasting anybody's time of reading this question.